# python requests error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Basically if I run a command curl:

```
curl -k -u user:pass --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' --request POST --data '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>' --url https://rhtpcapc001:8182/pc/center/webservice/datasources/dataSourceConsoleName/Data%20Aggregator%40RHTPCADA201/itemids
```

I have the following answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ItemIDResults><ItemIDResult 
LocalID="9528017" ItemID="828570"/></ItemIDResults>
```

I made a script in python to run this command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
}

data = {
'<LocalID ID': '"9528017"/>'
}

response = requests.post('https://rhtpcapc001:8182/pc/center/webservice/datasources/dataSourceConsoleName/Data%20Aggregator%40RHTPCADA201/itemids', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False, auth=('user', 'pass'))

print (response.encoding)
print (response.headers['Content-Type'])
print (response.headers)
print (response.text)
print (response.content)
print (response.reason)`
```

and gives me the following error:

> ISO-8859-1 text/plain {'Set-Cookie':
>   'JSESSIONID=md1waumsuoe81jceaxacbqgid;Path=/pc;Secure', 'Expires':
>   'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Date':
>   'Tue, 09 Apr 2019 10:28:54 GMT', 'Content-Length': '173', 'Server':
>   'Jetty(9.3.5.v20151012)'} JAXBException occurred : ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.. ParseError
>   at [row,col]:[1,1] Message: Content is not allowed in prolog..
>   b'JAXBException occurred : ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]\nMessage:
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.. ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[1,1]\nMessage: Content is not allowed in prolog.. ' Bad
>   Request

I think the problem is the encoding. When I run only the command curl:

COMMAND:

```
curl -k -u user:pass --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' --request POST --data '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>' --url https://rhtpcapc001:8182/pc/center/webservice/datasources/dataSourceConsoleName/Data%20Aggregator%40RHTPCADA201/itemids
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ItemIDResults><ItemIDResult LocalID="9528017" ItemID="828570"/></ItemIDResults>
```

in the answer we see encoding ="UTF-8"

in the python script with the response.encoding I see the encoding ISO-8859-1

thank you in advance for all the help.

BR

David

Comment: In your script, you set data to something (`'<LocalID ID': '"9528017"/>'` - which looks kind of strange) - but on the command line, you pass in empty data. Which one is the correct one?

Comment: @AndersLindahl you're right. It was a wrong copy / paste. I already edited with the correct curl command. Thanks.

Comment: What is the response if you change `data = {
'<LocalID ID': '"9528017"/>'
}` to `data = {
'<LocalID ID': '"9528017"/>'.encode('utf-8')
}`

Comment: @Frans Still giving error. The result is: 'ascii'  'text/plain' and gives the same errors 'Content is not allowed in prolog .. ParseError at'

Comment: It think I know whats wrong: In the curl you are sending XML `'<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>'`. In the Python script you are sending a dict `{
'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
}`.  

Could you try these options:
`data = '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>'`
or 
`data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' \
       '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>'`
or
`data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' \
       '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>'.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @Frans   Worked with the 1st option `data = '<LocalIDs><LocalID ID="9128615"/></LocalIDs>'`  Thank you very much for your help.